# Может ли быть переполнена очередь, созданная с помощью библиотеки queue в с++?

Tags: c++, очередь

В частности, может ли появиться ошибка, если в такую очередь добавили 9'000'000 элементов по 4 байта?

Comment: А у Вас уже есть пол террабайта оперативки?

Comment: верните нули назад! А то так не интересно

Comment: @KoVadim, зачем столько ОЗУ? Есть же файл подкачки.

Comment: там вначале было на три нуля больше

Comment: Да, виноват, извините, намудрил с нулями

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы мы за вас умножили количество элементов на размер элемента, чтобы узнать сколько нужно памяти для их хранения?

Comment: Нет, я лишь хотел узнать, чем ограничено количество элементов (или доступная для них память) в очереди

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вместимость любого контейнера в C++ ограничена исключительно доступным объёмом виртуальной памяти.

Причём в случае с `std::queue` этот объём не обязан быть непрерывным. Это связано с тем, что `std::queue` по умолчанию строится поверх `std::deque`, хранящего в себе совокупность относительно небольших кусков памяти.

Соответственно, для того, чтобы вместить 9*10<sup>9</sup> 64-байтных элементов, нам потребуется 536,44 гигабайта памяти. Чтобы орудовать таким объёмом данных, потребуется выполнить два условия:

1. Установить 64-разрядную ОС, иначе у стандартной библиотеки C++ не будет даже теоретической возможности разместить в памяти более трёх гигабайт данных.
2. Обеспечить наличие такого объём свободной памяти. То есть у вас **либо должно стоять ОЗУ огромных объёмов** (что крайне дорого), **либо соответствующим образом настроен файл подкачки** (что доступно на любом компьютере, но накладывает одно ограничение — невозможность последовательного прохода по очереди или её части без снижения производительности не только вашей программы, но и системы в целом).

*Примечание: ответ актуален для первой редакции вопроса, где фигурировало 9'000'000'000 64-байтных элементов.*

Comment: Я сам немного перегнул с числами (исправил с 64 байт на 4 и с 9*10^9 на 9*10^6), но ответ получил, спасибо

Comment: влезет, влезет на 32битной системе такой объем памяти (300мегабайт влазит точно). И это давно уже не "дорого"

Comment: @KoVadim, 32-разнядная система с её четырёхбайтовыми указателями при всём желании не сможет предоставить программе более четырёх гигабайт памяти (минус верхние 1-2ГБ на отображение ядра ОС, минус стеки, минус различные файловые отображения, включая DLL). Согласен, есть PAE и сколь угодно большие файловые отображения. Но C++ STL не умеет с ними обращаться.

Comment: так не нужны гигабайты, нужно то около пол гигабайта (накладными расходами можно принебречь)

Comment: @KoVadim, вы на порядок ошиблись. 9'000'000'000*64(на элемент)/1024(Б в КБ)/1024(КБ в МБ)/1024 (МБ в ГБ) = 536.4418 ГБ.

Comment: @KoVadim, а, всё, увидел, что `извините, намудрил с нулями`.

Comment: "Вместимость любого контейнера в C++ ограничена исключительно доступным объёмом виртуальной памяти." - это слишком сильное утверждение. Например, вместимость `std::vector` ограничена максимальным размером массива. А это, в зависимости от платформы, может быть на порядки меньше, чем доступный объём памяти.

Comment: "Файл подкачки снижает производительность" - а это откуда? Файл подкачки снижает производительность только тогда, когда необходимо его использование. Но в такой ситуации без файла подкачки программа *вообще бы не работала*. Что тогда означает слово "снижает"? "Снижает" по отношению к чему?

Comment: @AnT `А это, в зависимости от платформы, может быть на порядки меньше, чем доступный объём памяти` — вы про сегментную модель памяти? Я специально уточнил, что память виртуальная, то есть часть архитектур и подходов даже не рассматривается.

Comment: @AnT `Но в такой ситуации без файла подкачки программа вообще бы не работала. Что тогда означает слово "снижает"` — `снижает производительность ... системы в целом`. Говоря простыми словами — использование подкачки заставляет систему виснуть, когда программа из вопроса начинает активно работать с очередью. Кстати, спасибо за замечание, уточнил эту формулировку в вопросе. `"Снижает" по отношению к чему` — по отношению к скорости работы при наличии честной полтерабайтной оперативной памяти.

Comment: @AnT, переписал тот фрагмент. Что думаете насчёт новой редакции? Стал ли он более корректным?

Comment: @Arhad, наверное в реальности будет еще и overhead? А если место сразу не резервировать, то пожалуй и двукратный?

Answer (score 4):

Ваша очередь основана на каком-то стандартном контейнере.

Каждый стандартный контейнер имеет метод `max_size()`, возвращающий теоретический верхний предел максимального количества элементов данного типа в данном контейнере. Эта величина определяется особенностями платформы и данной реализации контейнера.

В дополнение к этому возможность наращивать размер контейнера может быть ограничена обстоятельствами времени выполнения, т.е. возможностью выделять дополнительную память.